# How to do rewrite this URL?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, model-view-controller

My url

```
site.com/index.php/Article/ArticleList
```

I want to be  it

```
site.com/Article/ArticleList
```

I didn't it. How rewrite htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php/$1/$2 [NC,L]
```